# Should I use puppeteer as part of my backend?

Tags: node.js, server, headless, puppeteer

Lets say I want to create a front-end where multiple users can send a request to a server that scrapes some links off a website, would puppeteer be able to process it concurrently/atleast fast enough or should I consider a different method?

Also, is there any possible way to load a page in a headless browser instance(with js enabled) on a mobile device? How could I go about coding my own headless browser in javascript if its possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always deploy your node.js instance via PM2 and spawn multiple processes concurrently to handle the incoming load.  You should restrict the total processes to the total number of cores available to your box, but otherwise this would work fine.

Whether or not this could handle your load depends on your server, the workload, and the expected throughout.  You'd need to do some load testing to make that determination for your system.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. My knowledge is limited in the area but essentially this method would handle each request in any one of the spawned instances?

Comment: Right, here's a pretty decent guide to getting something like this up and running: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04#set-up-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-server