# Using Puppeteer in an express backend to create my own API?

Tags: express, nginx, puppeteer, pm2

Trying to understand if this is feasible/possible for my personal project. I want to use puppeteer or I guess in this case puppeteer-core to scrape data from a webpage as a backend process and serve the **scraped** data in my frontend to users so I could create my own API.

To my understanding, I could use puppeteer-core so I could set my own environmental variables for my server environment.

According to this [Should I use puppeteer as part of my backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092124/should-i-use-puppeteer-as-part-of-my-backend)

I would use PM2 to manage and daemonize my so-call API application  along with NGINX as a reverse proxy server to handle users' requests for data.

Store the **scraped** data in Mongodb.

I am not sure what other problems or obstacles I need to address however. Would like additional guidance or advice to see if I have a good starting understanding of the problem scope.

Comment: Are you planning on providing scraping on demand as response to requests, or the scraping is independent of requests, ran regularly, and is only used to populate the database?

Comment: @AnasTiour I originally was scraping on demand as a response, without using a database at all. However this seems rather slow and now I am considering using mongodb to store my scraped data. 

If I wanted to do independent scraping that is ran regularly to populate a database, how would I go about it?
I have gotten recommendations from others to use node-cron in order to schedule my scrape processes to every hour, day, etc.

Comment: Populating a database is much easier, and is the way to go in 90% of the cases. The tricky part is not what you will use for the cron jobs, but if you are going to use NodeJS, you can go with PuppeteerJS, or with basic Http requests libraries, depending on the websites you are planning to scrape, which will make your life much easier. If you insist on using PuppeteerJS, make sure to survey your options on running Puppeteer on Docker and on Serverless. Besides that, I can't be much help to you, without knowing more of your use case.

Comment: @AnasTiour To elaborate further on my use case, I wanted to make a sports-related API, where users can request for athletes' personal data (weight, height, hometown, country-of-origin, etc, win-loss-records), and  event details of competition (date of event, location of event, people who are competing, etc) .

I wanted scheduled daily or weekly scraping  to gather athlete data and events details as they are announced on the website I am scraping. Events don't happen everyday like baseball so I do not need to scrape as frequently.

Comment: @AnasTiour PS: I am using axios as my http request library.

Comment: I guess your use case requires you to just update the data few times daily. Are you using axios to scrape data or the websites you scrape require you to use Puppeteer?

Comment: @AnasTiour Sorry I must've been unclear about the usage of an http request library. I was using simply axios to make http calls from my frontend to the backend of my app, upon a request to my backend, the backend would use puppeteer to scrape the data from the source site, and send the scrape results as a response to the frontend to render. This likely suboptimal process of using scraped data was slow however. My heroku hosted app would take roughly ~10 seconds to render the scraped results.

Comment: Sir, this is a nice app. I can see that your data is not something that changes often, and the website Tapology seems like it is scraper friendly, so switching to some lighter solution might be better, but Puppeteer will do just fine. I would advise to close this question, we kind of got off rails too much for SO taste

Comment: FYI it's __scraped__ (and __scrape__, __scraping__, __scraper__) not scrapped